# In Youtube data api v3 GET Videos request, what exactly indicates that video has been checked and is marked age restricted?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Youtube data API GET Videos request has field "contentDetails.contentRating.ytRating" (indicated [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#contentDetails.contentRating.ytRating).
But for some of the videos, the field "contentRating" is empty, thus does not contain **ytAgeRestricted** value. Does that mean that those videos are NOT age restricted? Or it means that those videos are simply have not been checked by Youtube? Are there any videos which are not checked by Youtube and have no indication on age restriction?

Example of video ID with empty contentRating in response - `k5fmfdQU5lw`

```json
{
  "videoInfo": {
    "etag": "m4HIaaqSXP5OLjanlhkLAZUQK8o",
    "items": [
      {
        "contentDetails": {
          "caption": "false",
          "contentRating": {},
          "definition": "hd",
          "dimension": "2d",
          "duration": "PT20M10S",
          "licensedContent": true,
          "projection": "rectangular"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: As a YouTube video creator by accessing https://studio.youtube.com/video/VIDEO_ID/edit you can [define yourself the age restriction of a given video](https://imgur.com/a/KHs79Es). Here is the [Learn more](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2950063?hl=en) link. However if you find a video which is age restricted (such as [`50kd0izeOog`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=50kd0izeOog)) and doesn't have the `contentRating` field, then let me know and I will step in and propose a solution.